# How to combine geom_map and geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, maps, ggrepel, geom-point, geom-map

I am trying to combine `geom_map` and `geom_point` in `ggplot2` using 2 data frames. When running the first part with `geom_point` only, I get the right plot. When running both combined geoms_ I get the error:

> "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
> function. Defaulting to continuous. Error in `f()`: ! Aesthetics must
> be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): label = year.  Did
> you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?"

Here are the data and not functioning codes:

**Data**

```
dput(earthquakes1)
structure(list(year = c(1751L, 1751L, 1770L, 1775L, 1775L, 1784L, 
1793L, 1842L, 1860L, 1864L, 1887L, 1953L, 1994L, 2010L, 2018L, 
2021L, 2022L), location_name = c("HAITI: PORT-AU-PRINCE", "HAITI:  PORT-AU-PRINCE", 
"HAITI: PORT-AU-PRINCE", "HAITI: UNKNOWN LOCATION", "HAITI: UNKNOWN LOCATION", 
"HAITI:  PETIT GOAVE,LEOGANE,PORT-AU-PRINCE", "HAITI:  SANTO DOMINGO (ST DOMINGUE)", 
"HAITI:  CAP-HAITIEN", "HAITI: ANSE-A-VEAU", "HAITI:  JACMEL", 
"HAITI:  MOLE SAINT NICOLAS", "HAITI", "HAITI: SAINT-LOUIS DU NORD", 
"HAITI:  PORT-AU-PRINCE", "HAITI: PORT-DEX-PAIX", "HAITI", "HAITI: NIPPES"
), longitude = c(-72.3, -72.3, -73.4, -72.4, -72.4, -72.3, -72.3, 
-72.2, -73.35, -72.53, -74.4, -73.4, -72.799, -72.533, -73.013, 
-73.475, -73.337), latitude = c(18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 19, 19, 18.5, 
19, 19.75, 18.52, 18.2, 19.7, 18.4, 19.803, 18.457, 20.034, 18.408, 
18.458), mag = c(5.61358333333333, 5.61358333333333, 5.61358333333333, 
5.61358333333333, 5.61358333333333, 5.62857666666667, 5.61358333333333, 
8.1, 5.61358333333333, 7.01098333333333, 5.88847666666666, 5.7, 
5.4, 7, 5.9, 7.2, 5.3), deaths = c(NA, NA, 200L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5000L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 4L, 316000L, 18L, 2248L, 2L), any_missing = c("Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Not Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Not Missing", 
"Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing"
)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

> dput(world1)

structure(list(long = c(-72.8045883178711, -72.8222122192383, 
-73.0779800415039, -73.2852554321289, -73.2764129638672, -73.1706085205078, 
-73.0691375732422, -72.9192352294922, -72.8045883178711, -71.7792510986328, 
-71.7574234008789, -71.7114715576172, -71.7069320678711, -71.753173828125, 
-71.7464828491211, -71.647216796875, -71.6453094482422, -71.6570281982422, 
-71.7420425415039, -71.80712890625, -71.786376953125, -71.733642578125, 
-71.72705078125, -71.7432174682617, -71.82421875, -71.8665084838867, 
-71.9868698120117, -72.0003890991211, -71.9403839111328, -71.87255859375, 
-71.7619171142578, -71.7372589111328, -71.7637634277344, -71.768310546875, 
-71.8529281616211, -71.9460906982422, -72.0020523071289, -72.0598602294922, 
-72.5035629272461, -72.55322265625, -72.5918960571289, -72.63330078125, 
-72.7552719116211, -72.8766632080078, -73.1600570678711, -73.2722702026367, 
-73.3851547241211, -73.5148391723633, -73.64404296875, -73.747314453125, 
-73.82470703125, -73.8391571044922, -73.8849639892578, -73.9894485473633, 
-74.0854034423828, -74.1946334838867, -74.4190444946289, -74.4599609375, 
-74.4781265258789, -74.3875045776367, -74.2844772338867, -74.2277374267578, 
-74.100341796875, -73.9759750366211, -73.8624954223633, -73.68701171875, 
-73.5915985107422, -72.9172821044922, -72.7893524169922, -72.7394485473633, 
-72.6959991455078, -72.6597671508789, -72.6180648803711, -72.4181137084961, 
-72.3760757446289, -72.3467330932617, -72.34765625, -72.4652328491211, 
-72.6491241455078, -72.8110885620117, -72.7412109375, -72.7679672241211, 
-72.7417984008789, -72.7032241821289, -72.8634262084961, -73.052734375, 
-73.3155212402344, -73.3963394165039, -73.4383773803711, -73.4005355834961, 
-73.3153305053711, -73.2177734375, -73.1177749633789, -72.8765106201172, 
-72.6370162963867, -72.429931640625, -72.2198257446289, -71.9542922973633, 
-71.834716796875, -71.7792510986328, -72.6640625, -72.6234893798828, 
-72.6388702392578, -72.7397918701172, -72.84423828125, -72.87841796875, 
-72.8993225097656, -72.9603576660156, -72.90673828125, -72.8514633178711, 
-72.791015625, -72.6640625), lat = c(18.7776851654053, 18.7071285247803, 
18.7909183502197, 18.896728515625, 18.9540538787842, 18.96728515625, 
18.9320316314697, 18.8614749908447, 18.7776851654053, 19.7181644439697, 
19.6881847381592, 19.486572265625, 19.4219722747803, 19.324462890625, 
19.2858390808105, 19.1959476470947, 19.1635246276855, 19.1307621002197, 
19.0455074310303, 18.9870128631592, 18.9200210571289, 18.8563976287842, 
18.80322265625, 18.73291015625, 18.6455078125, 18.6141605377197, 
18.6103515625, 18.597900390625, 18.5125980377197, 18.4162120819092, 
18.34130859375, 18.2707996368408, 18.2039546966553, 18.0391597747803, 
18.119140625, 18.1860847473145, 18.2120113372803, 18.2285633087158, 
18.2199230194092, 18.2083988189697, 18.1869144439697, 18.1762218475342, 
18.1561527252197, 18.1517562866211, 18.2056140899658, 18.2335453033447, 
18.2511730194092, 18.245361328125, 18.2290534973145, 18.1902351379395, 
18.1217784881592, 18.0582027435303, 18.0418949127197, 18.1431655883789, 
18.2151355743408, 18.2691898345947, 18.34619140625, 18.39306640625, 
18.4500007629395, 18.6247062683105, 18.6566886901855, 18.6626949310303, 
18.64111328125, 18.6014156341553, 18.575439453125, 18.5653324127197, 
18.5223636627197, 18.4557132720947, 18.434814453125, 18.442138671875, 
18.4682140350342, 18.5153312683105, 18.55078125, 18.5586910247803, 
18.574462890625, 18.6237297058105, 18.6749515533447, 18.7435531616211, 
18.8941402435303, 19.0715827941895, 19.13134765625, 19.2406253814697, 
19.3418464660645, 19.4410648345947, 19.5260753631592, 19.6107425689697, 
19.6373043060303, 19.65869140625, 19.7221183776855, 19.8074226379395, 
19.8545894622803, 19.8836917877197, 19.90380859375, 19.9280757904053, 
19.90087890625, 19.8132801055908, 19.74462890625, 19.7216796875, 
19.6967296600342, 19.7181644439697, 20.0375003814697, 20.01416015625, 
19.98583984375, 20.00341796875, 20.0354499816895, 20.0274410247803, 
20.0314464569092, 20.062255859375, 20.0858402252197, 20.0936508178711, 
20.0918941497803, 20.0375003814697), group = c(688, 688, 688, 
688, 688, 688, 688, 688, 688, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 
689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 689, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 690, 
690, 690, 690, 690, 690), order = c(46417L, 46418L, 46419L, 46420L, 
46421L, 46422L, 46423L, 46424L, 46425L, 46427L, 46428L, 46429L, 
46430L, 46431L, 46432L, 46433L, 46434L, 46435L, 46436L, 46437L, 
46438L, 46439L, 46440L, 46441L, 46442L, 46443L, 46444L, 46445L, 
46446L, 46447L, 46448L, 46449L, 46450L, 46451L, 46452L, 46453L, 
46454L, 46455L, 46456L, 46457L, 46458L, 46459L, 46460L, 46461L, 
46462L, 46463L, 46464L, 46465L, 46466L, 46467L, 46468L, 46469L, 
46470L, 46471L, 46472L, 46473L, 46474L, 46475L, 46476L, 46477L, 
46478L, 46479L, 46480L, 46481L, 46482L, 46483L, 46484L, 46485L, 
46486L, 46487L, 46488L, 46489L, 46490L, 46491L, 46492L, 46493L, 
46494L, 46495L, 46496L, 46497L, 46498L, 46499L, 46500L, 46501L, 
46502L, 46503L, 46504L, 46505L, 46506L, 46507L, 46508L, 46509L, 
46510L, 46511L, 46512L, 46513L, 46514L, 46515L, 46516L, 46517L, 
46519L, 46520L, 46521L, 46522L, 46523L, 46524L, 46525L, 46526L, 
46527L, 46528L, 46529L, 46530L), region = c("Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", 
"Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti", "Haiti"), subregion = c("Ile de la Gonave", 
"Ile de la Gonave", "Ile de la Gonave", "Ile de la Gonave", "Ile de la Gonave", 
"Ile de la Gonave", "Ile de la Gonave", "Ile de la Gonave", "Ile de la Gonave", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ile de la Tortue", 
"Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", 
"Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", 
"Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue", "Ile de la Tortue")), row.names = c(NA, 
-112L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
 #libraries 
 library(tidyverse)
    library(maps)
    library(viridis)
    library(ggrepel)
#plot
ggplot( earthquakes1, aes(longitude, latitude, label = year)) +
      geom_point(data = earthquakes1, aes(longitude, latitude, size = mag, color= mag ))+
     geom_text_repel(box.padding = 0.5, max.overlaps = Inf) +
    
     geom_map(data= world1, map = world1, aes(long, lat, map_id = region ), color= "black", fill="lightgray", show.legend= FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `geom_map` is trying to use the information from `aes` that you provide in the first line, `ggplot( earthquakes1, aes(longitude, latitude, label = year))`. So, when you are going to add another datasource, then you want to add `inherit.aes = FALSE`, so that it will only use what you provide in that function, which is in `geom_map` in this case.

```
#libraries 
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(viridis)
library(ggrepel)

#plot
ggplot(earthquakes1, aes(longitude, latitude, label = year)) +
  geom_map(
    data = world1,
    map = world1,
    aes(map_id = region),
    color = "black",
    fill = "lightgray",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(longitude, latitude, size = mag, color = mag)) +
  geom_text_repel(box.padding = 0.5, max.overlaps = Inf)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks Prof AndrewGB. Much appreciated.